# Dartlang: How to have clickable rows in a table and access a particular cell in the table?

Tags: dart

I have a dart code, that fills up a table from a List. Here is the code before I explain my problem:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

class RowData {
  //Class for the values to be stored in each row
  int studentId;
  String name;
  int math;
  int science;
}

class Table {
  static StreamController<int> controller =
      new StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  Stream<int> updateStream = controller.stream;

  List<RowData> rows = new List<RowData>(); //contains the default rows
  List<String> downloadIds =
      new List<String>(); //should contain the id's of the selected rows

  TableElement table;
  var tBody;

  /* Takes in a List<Rows> of rows, draws a
   * html Table, and returns it as a Table Element.
   */
  TableElement drawTable() {
    this.table = new TableElement();
    this.table.classes.add("events_table");
    this.tBody = this.table.createTBody();
    Element head = this.table.createTHead();
    head.style.backgroundColor = "#003B70";

    this.table.tHead.addRow()
      ..insertCell(0).nodes.add(new Element.tag("div")..text = "Student ID")
      ..insertCell(1).nodes.add(new Element.tag("div")..text = "Student Name")
      ..insertCell(2).nodes.add(new Element.tag("div")..text = "Maths Score")
      ..insertCell(3).nodes.add(new Element.tag("div")..text = "Science Score");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      this.tBody.insertRow(i)
        ..insertCell(0).text = rows[i].studentId.toString()
        ..insertCell(1).text = rows[i].name.toString()
        ..insertCell(2).text = rows[i].math.toString()
        ..insertCell(3).text = rows[i].science.toString()
        ..onClick.listen((e) => downloadTrigger(e));
    }
    return (this.table);
  }

  void decodeJson(String input) {
    List decoded = JSON.decode(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < decoded["ScoreReport"].length; i++) {
      rows.add(new Row()
        ..studentId = decoded["ScoreReport"][i]["studentId"]
        ..name = decoded["ScoreReport"][i]["name"]
        ..math = decoded["ScoreReport"][i]["math"]
        ..science = decoded["ScoreReport"][i]["science"]);
    }
  }

  downloadTrigger(Event e) {
    var download_id =
        ((e.target as Element).parent as TableRowElement).rowIndex;
    print(download_id);
    this.table.tBodies[0].rows[download_id].style.backgroundColor = "#4caf50";
    var test = this.table.tBodies[0].rows[download_id].nodes.toString();
    print(test);
  }
}
```

This class is called by a different class that would send in a JSON file to first populate the Rows and then calls for the table function to draw the function.

Right now, I am trying to download the students report, when clicked on the respective row, for instance, if someone clicks on the third row, I need to be able to get the Student id in the third row and once I get the id, I know how to trigger the download.

I am struck at the point of getting the student Id, I could get the node where the user clicked, but I can not proceed with that node, because two students could have the same name or same scores, but the Id's differ. Right know I have a simple print statement for the Id's, when I try to print, the console would show a "td" which kind of makes sense to me. I am new to dart and would like to get some help, on this.

Simply, when the user clicks anywhere on a particular row, I need the Student Id in that row.

Thanks in advance, sorry for the long description.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work after the table was added to the DOM:

```
ElementList rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
rows.onClick.listen((event) {
  print(event.target.children[0].text);
})
```